# Can multiple OAuth 2 authorization grant flows be shown in one application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, okta

I am new to Spring Security and Spring in general and I'm currently attempting to create a simple Spring web application that demonstrates the Client Credential and Authorization Grant flows in Spring Security OAuth2 using Okta as an authorization provider.

Currently the application has two html buttons, each linked to one of the flows (oktaAuth and oktaClient). When the user clicks a button it should follow the appropriate flow and retrieve a JWT from the authorization server, which is already configured. Once it has authenticated the application and/or user the app should use the granted token to retrieve JSON information from an AWS Api.

My question is whether it is possible to demonstrate both flows within one application, and if so what changes need to be made to accommodate the differences in each?

Here are my code snippets:
Main Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Client
@RestController
public class BootAndOAuthApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(BootAndOAuthApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Autowired
  OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;  

  @RequestMapping("/user")
  public Principal user(Principal principal) {
      return principal;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
.and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
      .and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  private Filter ssoFilter() {
      CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
      List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
      filters.add(ssoFilter(oktaAuth(), "/login/oktaAuth"));

      OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oktaClientFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login/oktaClient");
      OAuth2RestTemplate oktaClientTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oktaClient(), oauth2ClientContext);

      oktaClientFilter.setRestTemplate(oktaClientTemplate);     
      UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(oktaClientResource().getTokenInfoUri(), oktaClient().getClientId());
      tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oktaClientTemplate);

      oktaClientFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
      filters.add(oktaClientFilter);
      filter.setFilters(filters);
      return filter;
  }

  private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
      OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
      OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
      oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
      UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
      client.getClient().getClientId());
      tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
      oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
      return oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter;
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("oktaAuth")
  public ClientResources oktaAuth() {
      return new ClientResources();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("oktaClient.client")
  public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails oktaClient() {
      return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("oktaClient.resource")
  public ResourceServerProperties oktaClientResource() {
      return new ResourceServerProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(
OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
      FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
      registration.setFilter(filter);
      registration.setOrder(-100);
      return registration;
  }
}

class ClientResources {
  @NestedConfigurationProperty
  private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

  @NestedConfigurationProperty
  private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

  public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
      return client;
  }

  public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
      return resource;
  }
}
```

application.yml

```
oktaAuth:
  client:
    clientId: [redacted - credentials 1]
    clientSecret: [redacted - credentials 1]
    accessTokenUri: {Okta Token Url}
    userAuthorizationUri: {Okta Authorize Url}
    grant-type: authorization_code
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    scope: [redacted]
  resource:
    userInfoUri:  {Okta User Url}
    preferTokenInfo: false
oktaClient:
  client:
    clientId: [redacted - credentials 2]
    clientSecret: [redacted - credentials 2]
    accessTokenUri:{Okta Token Url}
    client-authentication-scheme: form
    grant-type: client_credentials
    scope:[redacted]
  resource:
    user-info-uri: {Okta User Url}
    preferTokenInfo: true
```

As I stated most of this is new to me so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you need it just as a demo, why not using a different client ID for each flow? Edit: Looking at the application.yml, you are probably already doing that ;-) I don't know much about Okta, so I have just the OAuth2 perspective.

Comment: Yes, I am using two different Okta "Apps" so there are two sets of client credentials. I'm just not sure if Spring even allows for multiple flows to be used within a single app. Do you have experience implementing OAuth flows in Spring apps?